# No puedo ingresar al visual studio 2015 express cuando ejecuto como administrador que puedo hacer?

Tags: visual-studio, .net, visual-studio-2015

cuando intento abrir mi visual studio 2015 express como modo administrador de esta forma [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui pongo mis credenciales como administrador de mi trabajo pero siempre me pasa este error en esta parte cuando intento loguearme [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no puedo ingresar , al intentar ingresar me marca este error en sing in
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando intento añadir una nueva cuenta , esta no me aparece pese a poner mi correo y mi contraseña de microsoft bien , por que pasa esto? y como lo puedo solucionar , estoy algo desesperado , muchas gracias

Comment: Ponte en contacto con el administrador de red, hay algún proxy/firewall que está denegando la conexión. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo al mensaje que muestras donde se pide usuario y contraseña,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me parece que se está tratando de instalar el software, pero tienes una restricción para poder instalar software, ahí **debes definir el usuario y contraseña de una cuenta administrador de tu pc**, si no la tienes debes requerir la ayuda al administrador o que te asignen una cuenta administradora de pc para que puedas instalar el software.

Con respecto a este problema, debes autenticarte en donde dice "Sign in", pero también debes pedir permisos al administrador de la red, ya que al parecer el problema es relacionado a permisos del proxy

[image: jorgesys web services]